# TYPO3 Form Bug? - The Prototype "standard" was not found

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-11.x

I just wanted to add a form to my new installed TYPO3 site.

The form looks good but in the frontend I get the following error:

```
***The Prototype "standard" was not found.***
```

I really do not understand what this message wants to tell me. After googeling the problem I came across following solution:

> editing the TypoScript template record and adding "Form (form) [EXT:form/Configuration/TypoScript/]" in "Include static (from extensions)[include_static_file]"

Even with that solution I'm stuck here.

Where are these files? How can I add a record to the template file?

I really appreciate any help here.

Thanks

FYI: My TYPO3 version is 11.5.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/UsingSetting/Entering.html#include-typoscript-from-extensions):

1. In the "Web > Template" module, select "Info / Modify"
2. Click "Edit the whole template record"
3. Chose the tab "Includes"
4. Click the templates to include in "Available Items"

Comment: Thanks! that was the problem... Forgot to include the extension!